# Battlelog How can i disable auto-join?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

When I am about to play battlefield 4, and I click "join", it will automaticly put me in the game as soon as its finished loading.

Is there any way I can disable that?

I can still remember that the old battlelog had a button to disable auto-join.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable it by going to general settings and disabling "Focus game when loading is complete"

[image: Settings, General]

Comment: Hee, i have tried that, and it doesnt work? I have disabled that button but it will still launch the game as soon as its loads

Comment: I will double check when I get home

Comment: The button is there though, it only doesnt work selected on and/or off

Comment: Never mind, its a bug that the nutton doesnt work for some people, thanks anyways